# T-SQL conditional AND statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, table-valued-parameters, sql-in

I'm trying to set up a stored procedure where I'm taking in a table value parameter and using it inside an IN statement to grab the results, the issue is the table value parameter can be empty, is there a way for me to conditionally insert an entire and statement?

```
declare @var int
--insert @var
declare @tvp tvp
--insert stuff (or not) into @tvp

SELECT t.foo1, t.foo2, t.foo3
FROM dbo.t t
WHERE t.foo4 = @var
IF(EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM @tvp)) 
   AND t.foo1 IN (SELECT @tvp.foo1 FROM @tvp)
```

this is what I'm going for conceptually, any help on what the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version assumes that results should still be returned even when @tvp is empty. It says that @tvp is either empty or t.foo1 is IN @tvp.

```
WHERE t.foo4 = @var AND
(  
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @tvp) 
    OR t.foo1 IN (SELECT @tvp.foo1 FROM @tvp)
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks, our dba is off leaving the programming team to learn sql, we look like monkeys in front of keyboards lol.

Answer (score 4):

Following your logic, you really just need parentheses:

```
WHERE t.foo4 = @var OR
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @tvp) OR
       t.foo1 IN (SELECT @tvp.foo1 FROM @tvp)
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @var int
--insert @var
declare @tvp tvp
--insert stuff (or not) into @tvp 
declare @tvpCount int = select count(*) from @tvp

SELECT distinct t.foo1, t.foo2, t.foo3
  FROM dbo.t t 
  join tvp
    on t.foo4 = @var
   and ( @tvpCount = 0 or t.foo1 = @tvp.foo1 )
```